# Powershell script not creating site folder

Tags: powershell, iis

This is powershell script to create IIS site and application pool. It creates site and application pool successfully but i dont see sitefolder been created. why?

```
$iisAppPoolName = "webtest.abc.com"
$iisAppPoolDotNetVersion = "v4.0"
$iisAppPoolManagedPipeLineMode = "0"
$iisAppName = "webtest.abc.com"
$directoryPath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\" + $iisAppPoolName
$SiteFolder = Join-Path -Path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot' -ChildPath  $iisAppName

#navigate to the app pools root
cd IIS:\AppPools\

#check if the app pool exists
if (!(Test-Path $iisAppPoolName -pathType container))
{
    #create the app pool
    $appPool = New-Item $iisAppPoolName
    $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value $iisAppPoolDotNetVersion
    $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedPipelineMode" -Value $iisAppPoolManagedPipeLineMode

}

#navigate to the sites root
cd IIS:\Sites\

 #check if the site exists
 if (Test-Path $iisAppName -pathType container)
 {
   return
 }

 #create the site
 $iisApp = New-Item $iisAppName -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=":80:" + $iisAppName} -physicalPath  $SiteFolder
 $iisApp | Set-ItemProperty -Name "applicationPool" -Value $iisAppPoolName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like when you define site properties this way there is no check for directory existance. When you do the same from GUI you would get error saying *The specified directory does not exist on the server*.

You could create folder just before you create the site. Like so:

```
#create the site
New-Item -Path $SiteFolder -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
$iisApp = New-Item $iisAppName -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=":80:" + $iisAppName} -physicalPath  $SiteFolder
$iisApp | Set-ItemProperty -Name "applicationPool" -Value $iisAppPoolName
```